# Open random page from sitemap.xml using PHP

Tags: php, sitemap

I need to create a php script that opens a random page from a wordpress blog's sitemap.xml but I really don't have a clue on how to do it. Can someone help me on this?

The sitemap is located here: http://designsuperstars.net/sitemap.xml

Any help is welcomed,
Bogdan

Comment: Uhmm...basically things glued together that I found on google but it doesn't work. It's the first time I'm using php so unfortunately I can't show you anything. I'm sorry if I'm looking lazy... If it's to much work on doing something like this, at least can you please tell me some hints?

Comment: If you've got code, you should add it to the question and explain why it's not working. You'll find people a lot more willing to help if you can show that you've tried to solve the problem yourself, even if your code doesn't work.

Comment: Or you describe the intention/functionality you want - maybe php is not the easiest way to solve your wordpress sitemap problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this simple script

```
$url = "http://designsuperstars.net/sitemap.xml" ;
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
$link = $xml->url[mt_rand(0,count($xml->url)-1)]->loc ; // Get Random Location 

Header("Location:" . $link); // Load any page
```